# Add LoT and LoF to a subsection

Tags: table-of-contents, tocbibind

Lots of examples out there about how to add LoT and LoF and Bib to ToC. But how to get from there to adding as a subsection?

```
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
\endgroup}

\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listtablename}{lot}
\endgroup}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your question is unclear. Your title says `Add to a subsection`, the text says `as a subsection`. Please do not post fragments only -- it does not compile

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code complete with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Package [`tocbasic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbasic) provides a feature `leveldown`. Using an article class leveling down means using `\subsection*` (or `\subsection`) instead of `\section*` for the heading. Adding the heading to the table of contents can be done using feature `totoc`. A basic example with `article` would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\tocbasicautomode
\setuptoc{lof}{leveldown}
\setuptoc{lof}{totoc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftoc[\listfigurename]{lof}

\section{Test}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \rule{1cm}{1cm}
  \caption{Black rule}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Contents, List of figures and first section]

You can do the same for the list of tables using `\listtablename` and `lot` instead of `\listfigurename` and `lof`.

Note, that you can do the same with options `listof=totoc,listof=leveldown` if  you are using a KOMA-Script class:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,listof=leveldown]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\section{Test}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \rule{1cm}{1cm}
  \caption{Black rule}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to directly add the LoF to the ToC using `tocbasic` while still using the article class?

Comment: @TakingItCasual I don't understand your question, because my *first example* already still shows this. Maybe you should ask a new question with minimal working example showing, what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Easily done with something like this :

```
\newcommand{\makelot}{
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of tables}
\listoftables
}

\newcommand{\makelof}{
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of figures}
\listoffigures
}
```

Then calling `\makelof` will call you the list of figures where you want it and that would be considered as a subsection in the ToC.

Be aware that it's just an addition to the ToC and not a redefinition of the command. Thus the styling and the documental behavior of you LoF will be standard.